# java collections iterator and garbage (android)

Tags: java, android, iterator

I've been running some tests on android using a complex hashmap structure.

My structure looks like this : `Map<Class<?>, HashMap<Object, Class<?>> mymap;` and I have a iterator prepared `Iterator< object > iterator;`
This structure holds about 1,000 objects at a time. Now I need to be able to iterate over these objects pretty fast.

I usually return a collection of my objects back, manually cast them and iterate over that collection. This is where my problem comes rears its head.

I do `Collection < object > returnedobjects = get all mymap.get(class).getvalues`. Then I do `iterator = returnedobjects.iterator;` then I do

```
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
  Box b = (Box)iterator.next();
  do box operations;
}
```

Or I try this way

```
for(Object o : returnedObjects)
{ 
  Box b : (Box) o;
  do box operations;
}
```

now With this setup the garbage collector runs like mad example output :

```
10-26 13:56:17.793: D/dalvikvm(5518): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3639K, 57% free 3543K/8195K, paused 15ms+18ms, total 135ms
10-26 13:56:21.013: D/dalvikvm(5518): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1753K, 57% free 3526K/8195K, paused 13ms+21ms, total 92ms
10-26 13:56:24.363: D/dalvikvm(5518): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1743K, 57% free 3525K/8195K, paused 24ms+17ms, total 116ms
10-26 13:56:27.653: D/dalvikvm(5518): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1738K, 57% free 3527K/8195K, paused 13ms+16ms, total 102ms
10-26 13:56:30.913: D/dalvikvm(5518): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1739K, 57% free 3526K/8195K, paused 14ms+18ms, total 95ms
10-26 13:56:34.153: D/dalvikvm(5518): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1737K, 57% free 3528K/8195K, paused 15ms+18ms, total 97ms
```

and it continues at that pace as long as my app is running.

Is there any way that I can manage all my objects without the gc running at such a crazy pace?

Comment: It's running about once every 3 seconds. Depending on what you're doing, that's not a "crazy pace". What are you doing in "do box operations" that generates garbage? From the code you posted, it's not clear that any garbage is being generated.

Comment: The do box operations is just currently multiplying by some random numbers to simulate actual calculations. Where the real issue comes up is every loop iterator = returnedobjects.iterator();  that call generates a lot of garbage along with 80-160 ms pauses is really causing me issues.

Comment: I suggest that you track memory usage for your app using [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html). Also look at the article ["Avoiding Memory Leaks"](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html). Alternatively, perhaps you can isolate the suspect code and run it under Sun's Java and use a nice Java profiling tool like JProfiler. Profiling can help pinpoint where the issue really is.

Comment: The problem with this setup is the hashmap's iterator. I am creating a lot of iterators per loop and those iterators are looping over all the values of the returned values. I've looked at the ddms output and that's where all the trouble's coming from. I was wondering is there another data structure that could be used instead of a hashmap because the hashmap iterator in a tight loop is really inefficient and creates a lot of garbage.